# Отображение связанных данных в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, связывание-данных

Имею MS Access базу данных со связанными таблицами. В студии штатными средствами добавил новый DataSource и Dataset (один класс (читай один DataTable) - одна таблица).

Пусть, для примера, у меня 2 таблицы: Table1 и Table2. 1 из столбцов Table1 - это ID в Table2. Теперь в DataSet.Table1.Row есть свойства ID, *другие столбцы*, Table2Row. В свою очередь Table2Row - это класс, соответствующий 1 строке таблицы Table2.

Теперь я хочу вывести таблицу Table1 в DataGrid, но так, чтобы вместо столбца Table2ID у меня отображались некоторые столбцы из соответствующей строки Table2.

Сейчас я сделал копирование DataTable первой таблицы, добавил туда нужные столбцы и в цикле foreach записал нужные значения из соответствующей строки таблицы Table2:

```
var fullTable = _dataSet.Ord;
fullTable.Columns.Add("CopyName");
fullTable.Columns.Add("ExecutorName");
fullTable.Columns.Add("OrdererName");
foreach (var row in fullTable.AsEnumerable())
{
     if (row.CopyRow != null) row["CopyName"] = row.CopyRow.Title;
     if (row.ExecutorRow != null) row["ExecutorName"] = row.ExecutorRow.Name;
     if (row.OrdererRow != null) row["OrdererName"] = row.OrdererRow.Name;
}
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли обойтись без лишнего копирования? Или как это сделать проще и наименее затратно.

Comment: использую WinForms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/665846/5796587 сделайте предварительный Join двух DataTable как в примере по ссылке и результат отдайте в DataGreedView

Answer (score 1):

Для начала сделайте Inner Join двух DataTable.
Оригинал на EnSO https://stackoverflow.com/a/665846/5796587

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("ColX", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("ColY", typeof(int));

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("ColZ", typeof(int));

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt1.NewRow();
    row["CustID"] = i;
    row["ColX"] = 10 + i;
    row["ColY"] = 20 + i;
    dt1.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dt2.NewRow();
    row["CustID"] = i;
    row["ColZ"] = 30 + i;
    dt2.Rows.Add(row);
}

var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["CustID"] equals (int)table2["CustID"]
             select new
             {
                 CustID = (int)table1["CustID"],
                 ColX = (int)table1["ColX"],
                 ColY = (int)table1["ColY"],
                 ColZ = (int)table2["ColZ"]
             };
```

Дальше все просто:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = results.ToList();
```

Преобразование в `List` обязательно, т.к. `DataGridView` не умеет отображать `IEnumerable`

Естественно редактирование этих данных в гриде не изменит состояние данных в таблицах и может быть выключено совсем. Для редактирования придется открывать исходные таблицы.

---

MSDN примеры для разных [**join на LiNQ**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin)

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое и менее затратное- это запросить объедененные данные запросом из СУБД.

Comment: Думал об этом. Но... 1) Представим ситуацию, что данные теперь нужно хранить в XML, например. 2) Хочется при редактировании максимально использовать автосгенерированный код адаптеров (Update в особенности)

Comment: Как вариант, ты можешь сам ручками из 2 ух DataTable заполнять DataGridView, затем написать обработчики событий и обновлять все в самих DataTable. Что-то другое на ум вообще не приходит.